# How to make a JavaFX modal child window not appear in alt-tab

Tags: java, javafx

I've got a JavaFX application, with a modal window that sets the main application window as the parent. When that pop-up window appears, my Ubuntu task switcher (alt-tab) seems to think that this is an entirely different window; both it and the main application window appear as choices. How can I configure JavaFX so that this window does not appear as a separate choice in alt-tab?

Here's a minimal example:

```
public class PopupExample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Stage window = new Stage();
        window.initOwner(primaryStage);
        window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        window.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: For me, this is a problem of the windows manager rather than java/fx. Until recently, there was a problem with displaying the window titles in the taskbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, It's very simple, just set `StageStyle.UTILITY` as an `initStyle` for the second `Stage`. By doing this, `Alt+Tab` shows one window.

The following code demonstrates how to cope with this issue:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class PopupExample extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        Button showPopUpbutton = new Button("Show Stage_TWO");
        showPopUpbutton.setOnAction(event -> showPopup());
        vBox.getChildren().add(showPopUpbutton);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 300, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Stage_One");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void showPopup()
    {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        Label label = new Label("Stage_TWO");
        Button closeStageButton = new Button("Close Stage_TWO");
        closeStageButton.setOnAction(event -> stage.close());
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(label, closeStageButton);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 200, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.setTitle("Stage_TWO");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```